# Linking audio elements together HTML/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm not entirely sure how to run a function that syncs up with the updating of a webpage.

I have a checkbox that runs a function if checked.

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="data.id" id="status" ng-model="data.status" class="Form-label-checkbox" ng-change="IfCheck(data.Url)">
```

The IfCheck function adds the url into an array, $scope.ids

JavaScript: //kind of psuedocode

```
$scope IfCheck(url){
    $scope.ids.push(object);}

$scope.Playall = function(){
    var audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
    for(var i = 0; i < audioElements.length; i++){
        audioElements[i].play();
    }
}
```

This seems to work well so far. The array ids gets populated with the URLs on the fly. Afterwards, I run ng-repeat on this array, and create an  element with the source as the url. This works as well.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in ids">
<audio controls>
                    <source src="{{data.Url | trustUrl}}" id = "Synth.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                    </audio> </div>
```

My problem is this now. Lets say I check two boxes, and create two audio players  on the fly. They play music if I click the play button. Is there a way to somehow make a button so that it will play both of them at the same time? I thought of something like

```
<button ng-click = "Playall()"> Playall </button>
```

but I'm not sure how to write the function to "link" to the created elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Playall()` function can look something like this:

```
$scope.Playall = function(){
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("audio")).forEach(audio => audio.play());
}
```

OR:

```
$scope.Playall = function(){
    var audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
    for(var i = 0; i < audioElements.length; i++){
        audioElements[i].play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with that is if I click this button, it will "double up" the playing. So the Playall function will have one playthrough, and at the same time the individual audio player will also start playing.

Comment: @ellusion What do you mean ? Does it play the same audio file more the once ?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("audio")` will get all the `audio` elements on the page, you may want to change that so it will get only the `audio` elements that should be started.

Comment: Exactly. So if I have 2 songs, it will play each file twice, at the same time

Comment: @ellusion Just add a class name to the `audio` elements that should be started by the `Playall` function and instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("audio")` use `document.querySelectorAll(".someClassName")` or `document.getElementsByClassName("someClassName")`

Comment: I want all <audio> elements to be played. It just somehow plays each track twice

Comment: @ellusion Can you edit your question to include the `Playall` function that you're using. In my answer there are 2 approaches for doing this, you can use one or the other but not both.

Comment: I am such a moron. I forgot to delete something, my bad. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @ellusion No worries. I'm glad I could help. Good luck.